# Finding Latitude & Longitude in Openstreet Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, latitude-longitude, openstreetmap

The below code will return the lat & lon values, when i click any where on the map. The result is `lon=8931183.8958044,lat=1456094.8596215`

```
map.events.register('click', map, handleMapClick);
function handleMapClick(e)
{
var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
alert(lonlat);
}
```

how to get the lat & lon exactly when clicking on the map what is the extact format for lat and lon?

Kindly advice me!

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with Google Maps?  If not you should remove that tag.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with OpenStreetMap? If not you should remove that tag/title. This is an *OpenLayers* issue.

Comment: I am using openstreet Map and I am getting the above issue.. its an openstreet issue!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
  //defining the projection
    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   
    var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

    //getting the bounds
    var mapbounds = map.getExtent();

    //transform bounds to lat& long
    var val = mapbounds.transform(toProjection, fromProjection );
```